# How to find the manufacture date of Microsoft Surface Laptop?

Tags: windows, powershell, bios

I am having hard time to find the manufacture date of my Surface Laptop. All the methods I found on the internet turned out to be unhelpful.

I tried these methods:
1.System Information
[image: cmd output]

2.In cmd `systeminfo | findstr /I /c:bios`

[image: cmd uotput]
I really doubt that this is the correct manufacture date :)

3.In cmd `systeminfo|find /i “Original Install Date”`

[image: cmd uotput]
This seems to be the date I reinstalled Windows after failing to install Ubuntu on the laptop.

4.Pressing “Win + R,” typing `regedit`

[image]

In the path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Hardware/Description/System` I get:

[image]

But the information is missing the field `SystemBiosDate`

How can I see the manufacture date of my Surface laptop.

P.S. I followed the instructions on this post: [https://www.maketecheasier.com/get-bios-version-information-in-windows](https://www.maketecheasier.com/get-bios-version-information-in-windows/)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason is that it is off topic for this site. This site is for computer programming, and your post is not a computer program.

Answer (score 1):

What about the warranty end date in the Surface App? (from the microsoft store)

If the original warranty is a year, and it ended on 16/12/2020, then take a year off?

[image: Surface Laptop App]

Answer (score 0):

There are two PowerShell commands you could try, but I suspect they may give the same output as your systeminfo command

```
wmic os get installdate
```

or

```
([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate)
```

likewise, for the BIOS

```
Get-WmiObject win32_bios
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But unfortunately, I got same results as my other tries. Thank you so much anyways

Comment: I have a feeling, given your reinstall, that these bits of information may be as good as you can get.

Comment: I also think so. I am planning to sell my laptop, so I need to know the manufacture date of it. Unfortunately, I can't disassemble the laptop to see information about some parts as it does not have any screws.

Comment: What is the model number? You might be able to find out when it was manufactured online

Comment: Also, have you tried the 'Surface App'? .. which you may not have installed, but can fetch from the Microsoft Store. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/find-out-which-surface-model-you-have-da204261-8d26-9351-8588-5b09632c9486

Comment: most reliable way is getting the age of the internal monitor. Here the powershell-command: Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class WMIMonitorID That gives you the ISO year and week plus some more info. BIOS-date and OS-date may change after each update/reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to check lot number, which is written on the sticker, the first two digits are production year and the second is the week of the year.